# floating divisions of equal size are different size when aligned on top of each other

Tags: css, html

i am trying to make two divisions in html equal in width. they should remain the same width, when they fit into one row, but also when they are aligned below each other.

The example is here: [sample](http://xn--audiobibelne-olb.wowogiengen.de/stackexchange.php)

When the two boxes fit into one row, it looks good:

[a busy cat http://xn--audiobibelne-olb.wowogiengen.de/div_in_one_row.png](http://xn--audiobibelne-olb.wowogiengen.de/div_in_one_row.png)

but if they float, it seems like my second div is smaller than the first

[two muppets http://xn--audiobibelne-olb.wowogiengen.de/div_in_one_column.png](http://xn--audiobibelne-olb.wowogiengen.de/div_in_one_column.png)

this is the complete code of the page:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title></title>
        <style>
            
            .container {margin:auto;}
            .container-inner {position:relative;left:-50%;float:right}
            .container-inner ul {position:relative;left:50%}
            .container-inner li {display:inline;line-height:normal; }
            .container-inner li div {display: table-row;}
            .container-inner a,.container-inner a:visited {color:#525252;text-decoration:none}
            .container-inner a:hover {text-decoration:underline}
            .container-inner li:last-child {border-right:none}          
            .FarbeNT {background: rgba(255,128,0,0.5)}
            .FarbeAT {background: rgba(0,255,0,0.5)}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
      <div class="container">
 <div class="container-inner">
  <ul>
   <li>
                <div class="FarbeAT">
                    <div style="background-color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.15);">
                        <a href="http://0_AudioBibel_NT_zip.zip">Das Neue Testament</a>
                        <a href="http://0_AudioBibel_NT_zip.zip"><img alt="0_AudioBibel_NT_zip.zip" src="audiobibelneu/assets/zip.png"/></a>
                    </div>
                    <div style="">
                        <p><a href="?Buch=evangelien_apostel">Evangelien &amp; Apostel</a></p>
                        <p><a href="?Buch=briefe">Briefe</a></p>
                        <p><a href="?Buch=offenbarung">Offenbarung</a></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
   <li style="display: inline">
                <div class="FarbeNT">
                    <div style="background-color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.15)">
                        <a href="http://0_AudioBibel_AT_zip.zip" title="Das alte Testament komplett als ZIP-Datei.">Das Alte Testament</a>
                        <a href="http://0_AudioBibel_AT_zip.zip" title="Das alte Testament komplett als ZIP-Datei."><img alt="0_AudioBibel_AT_zip.zip" src="audiobibelneu/assets/zip.png"/></a>
                    </div>
                    <div style="">
                        <p><a href="?Buch=geschichte">Ge&shy;schichts&shy;büc&shy;her</a></p>
                        <p><a href="?Buch=poesie">Poetische Bücher</a></p>
                        <p><a href="?Buch=prophetie">Prophetische Bücher</a></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
  </ul>
 </div>
</div>  
    </body>
</html>
```

**Edit at 2016-06-03 16:03 GMT+2**:
The only problem with my code sample is, that the orange box seems to be a little bit smaller than the green one when they are stacked like in the second picture.

I cant find a way to make both boxes equal in size, say 15em width and 8em height.

Comment: so you hope both are also equal width when float?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my stylesheet looks now like that:

```css
.container
{
    margin:auto;
    
}
.container-inner
{
    position:relative;
    left:-50%;
    float:right
}
.container-inner ul
{
    position:relative;
    left:50%
}
.container-inner li
{
    display:inline-block;
    line-height:normal;
    float:left;
    margin-right: 1em;
}
.container-inner a,.container-inner a:visited
{
    color:#525252;text-decoration:none
}
.container-inner a:hover
{
    text-decoration:underline
}
.container-inner li:last-child 
{
    border-right:none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I removed this line

> .container-inner li div {display: table-row;}

and updated this one:

> .container-inner li {display:inline-block;line-height:normal;float:left; }

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title></title>
        <style>
            
            .container {margin:auto;}
            .container-inner {position:relative;left:-50%;float:right}
            .container-inner ul {position:relative;left:50%}
            .container-inner li {display:inline-block;line-height:normal;float:left; }
            .container-inner a,.container-inner a:visited {color:#525252;text-decoration:none}
            .container-inner a:hover {text-decoration:underline}
            .container-inner li:last-child {border-right:none}          
            .FarbeNT {background: rgba(255,128,0,0.5)}
            .FarbeAT {background: rgba(0,255,0,0.5)}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
      <div class="container">
 <div class="container-inner">
  <ul>
   <li>
                <div class="FarbeAT">
                    <div style="background-color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.15);">
                        <a href="http://0_AudioBibel_NT_zip.zip">Das Neue Testament</a>
                        <a href="http://0_AudioBibel_NT_zip.zip"><img alt="0_AudioBibel_NT_zip.zip" src="assets/zip.png"/></a>
                    </div>
                    <div style="">
                        <p><a href="?Buch=evangelien_apostel">Evangelien &amp; Apostel</a></p>
                        <p><a href="?Buch=briefe">Briefe</a></p>
                        <p><a href="?Buch=offenbarung">Offenbarung</a></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
   <li style="display: inline">
                <div class="FarbeNT">
                    <div style="background-color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.15)">
                        <a href="http://0_AudioBibel_AT_zip.zip" title="Das alte Testament komplett als ZIP-Datei.">Das Alte Testament</a>
                        <a href="http://0_AudioBibel_AT_zip.zip" title="Das alte Testament komplett als ZIP-Datei."><img alt="0_AudioBibel_AT_zip.zip" src="assets/zip.png"/></a>
                    </div>
                    <div style="">
                        <p><a href="?Buch=geschichte">Ge&shy;schichts&shy;büc&shy;her</a></p>
                        <p><a href="?Buch=poesie">Poetische Bücher</a></p>
                        <p><a href="?Buch=prophetie">Prophetische Bücher</a></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
  </ul>
 </div>
</div>  
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hello @Shlomi Haver, this is not the expected answer.
I want the boxes to float left to right if there is enough room for both.
They may float top to bottom, if the room is too small. 
They did so with my code. But if you look at the second picture, you see that the orange box is a little bit smaller than the green one. But in my code the width is not set at all.

Comment: @WolfgangRoth look now, i think this is what you wanted.

Comment: yes, now it looks like i wanted it. i add the updated css as answer.

Comment: @WolfgangRoth you are right, in order to fix this you must define some widths to the elements in your page. what happens now is a result of everything being relational to the amount of text you entered.

Comment: sorry, but it doesnt work either :-( . the bottom orange box is still smaller than the top green box. IIRC, at home, I managed to get the size of the boxes equal. But my second problem (not mentioned here) would be, that i want the boxes align to the center of the available space, no matter if they are stacked horizontal or vertical. But i think, because the width of the then surrounding div-element would be dynamic, it is not possible to set it centered to its parent element / screen / body-element.

Comment: @WolfgangRoth I can recommend you to have a look at [http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid](BootStrap Grid), there grif system suppose to solve problems like yours.

Answer (score 0):

hello use display inline block for centering 2 divs with the same width i make it 50% of parent div anyway u can set any size u want and set vertical align to top

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title></title>
        <style>
            
            .container {margin:auto;}
            .container-inner ul {font-size: 0; padding: 0; text-align:center; }
            .container-inner li {
               display:inline-block;
               font-size: 13px;
               line-height:normal;
               text-align: left;
               width: 50%;
               vertical-align: top;
             }

            .container-inner a,.container-inner a:visited {color:#525252;text-decoration:none}
            .container-inner a:hover {text-decoration:underline}
            .container-inner li:last-child {border-right:none}          
            .FarbeNT {background: rgba(255,128,0,0.5)}
            .FarbeAT {background: rgba(0,255,0,0.5)}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
      <div class="container">
 <div class="container-inner">
  <ul>
   <li>
                <div class="FarbeAT">
                    <div style="background-color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.15);">
                        <a href="http://0_AudioBibel_NT_zip.zip">Das Neue Testament</a>
                        <a href="http://0_AudioBibel_NT_zip.zip"><img alt="0_AudioBibel_NT_zip.zip" src="audiobibelneu/assets/zip.png"/></a>
                    </div>
                    <div style="">
                        <p><a href="?Buch=evangelien_apostel">Evangelien &amp; Apostel</a></p>
                        <p><a href="?Buch=briefe">Briefe</a></p>
                        <p><a href="?Buch=offenbarung">Offenbarung</a></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
   <li>
                <div class="FarbeNT">
                    <div style="background-color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.15)">
                        <a href="http://0_AudioBibel_AT_zip.zip" title="Das alte Testament komplett als ZIP-Datei.">Das Alte Testament</a>
                        <a href="http://0_AudioBibel_AT_zip.zip" title="Das alte Testament komplett als ZIP-Datei."><img alt="0_AudioBibel_AT_zip.zip" src="audiobibelneu/assets/zip.png"/></a>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <p><a href="?Buch=geschichte">Ge&shy;schichts&shy;büc&shy;her</a></p>
                        <p><a href="?Buch=poesie">Poetische Bücher</a></p>
                        <p><a href="?Buch=prophetie">Prophetische Bücher</a></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
  </ul>
 </div>
</div>  
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sorry to say that, but this it doesnt work at all like i suppose it should.